# hover event only fire one element which you can see it on the snippet

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

```js
(function() {
  var _li = document.querySelectorAll('.filterList .filterItem');

  for (var i = 0; i < _li.length; i++) {
    var _nestedUl = _li[i].getElementsByClassName('nestedUl')[0];
    var _aLink = _li[i].getElementsByClassName('downIcon')[0];

    //alert(i + ':' + _li[i].className);

    function showNested(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      _nestedUl.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function hideNested(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      _nestedUl.style.display = 'none';
    }

    _aLink.addEventListener('mouseover', showNested, false);
    _aLink.addEventListener('mouseout', hideNested, false);

  }

}());
```

```css
ul.nestedUl {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="filterList">
  <li class="filterItem">
    <a href="" class="downIcon">
      课程 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="nestedUl">
      <li>
        <a href="" class="selected">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5 course
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5 course
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="filterItem">
    <a href="" class="downIcon">
      主题 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="nestedUl">
      <li>
        <a href="" class="selected">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5 subject
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5 subject
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="filterItem">
    <a href="" class="downIcon">
      排序 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="nestedUl">
      <li>
        <a href="" class="selected">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5 order
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5 order
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>


</ul>
```

what i wanna do is to show the ul element when mouse over it,that is ,to make a dropdown menu using pure javascript. 
but all shows the middle element, i've no idea what's wrong with it. seems that the grammer is right, what am i missing?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `_nestedUl` is same reference, and you just overriding it in for cycle. You can use js [function closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) here.

This code should work and you can optimize it, I just made minimal changes that you can understand difference.

```
  (function() {
  var _li = document.querySelectorAll('.filterList .filterItem');

    for (var i = 0; i < _li.length; i++) {
      var _nestedUl = _li[i].getElementsByClassName('nestedUl')[0];
      var _aLink = _li[i].getElementsByClassName('downIcon')[0];

      (function(nestedUl) {
        function showNested(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          nestedUl.style.display = 'block';
        }

        function hideNested(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          nestedUl.style.display = 'none';
        }

        _aLink.addEventListener('mouseover', showNested, false);
        _aLink.addEventListener('mouseout', hideNested, false);
     })(_nestedUl);
   }

}());
```

Comment: Thanks, it's about the closure and I have always do wrong with closure. I guess I am not really understanding it^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using CSS alone:

```css
ul.nestedUl {
  display: none;
}
.filterList > li:hover .nestedUl {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="filterList">
  <li class="filterItem">
    <a href="" class="downIcon">
      课程 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="nestedUl">
      <li>
        <a href="" class="selected">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5 course
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5 course
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="filterItem">
    <a href="" class="downIcon">
      主题 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="nestedUl">
      <li>
        <a href="" class="selected">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5 subject
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5 subject
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="filterItem">
    <a href="" class="downIcon">
      排序 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="nestedUl">
      <li>
        <a href="" class="selected">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5 order
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5 order
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp HTML5
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In your JavaScript, it always attaches the event to the last one, because of wrongly looping.

Comment: yeah,i know css, but i wanna know why my js not work. and this event here just attach to the middle one ,thanks

Comment: @franklee In your code `_nestedUl` always points to your last UL. Does it help? Or should I give you the answer myself?

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar, can you please tell me why is that？Thanks

Comment: it'll be better if you provide the code using javascript, which can fix my problem, Thanks